# Can I call fragment's method from another fragment?

Tags: android

I have a fragmentA, and I want to call fragmentB with method.

I'ave added

```
myFragment.my_tag=1;
myFragment.dialogPersonalProfile();
```

to transiction, thinking it will work, but none.
Can you suggest me?

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
      .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.baseinfo, null))
      .setPositiveButton(R.string.fill_profile,
       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
               ArtistProfileView myFragment = new ArtistProfileView();
               myFragment.my_tag=1;
               myFragment.dialogPersonalProfile();
               activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                  .replace(((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId(), myFragment)
                                                            .commit();
               }
        }).show();
```

When user is on FragmentA and click on a button, it should open FragmentB's methods, in my case it is profile editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to let the fragment life cycle do the job.

Set an argument to the FragmentB (in this case ArtistProfileView) and use it to call the function from the onCreateView.